# Azure Function: Can't figure out which ctor to call

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I am building an API that is published to Azure Functions. I currently have two working functions, and I've written a third that I can't get to work after deploying.

It works when running locally using `func start` and pointing `scriptFile` in `function.json` to the same transpiled file as I'm deploying to Azure.

This is what the contents look like when I download them from the function runtime:

```
├── host.json
├── node_modules/
├── FunctionA
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.js
│   └── index.js.map
├── proxies.json
├── FunctionB
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.js
│   └── index.js.map
└── FunctionC
    ├── function.json
    ├── index.js
    └── index.js.map
```

`FunctionA` and `FunctionB` work. The main difference in `FunctionC` is that this function has a dependency to a `node_modules` dependency, `@azure/cosmos`.

I build all my functions identically, `npx parcel build index.ts --target node`. According to the parcel docs:

> Target node and electron will not bundle package.json's dependencies

Exactly what I want, since the [developer guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#deploying-with-dependencies) state this is how you handle dependencies in an Azure Function using Javascript:

> 1. Install all requisite packages locally by running npm install.
> 2. Deploy your code, and ensure that the node_modules folder is included in the deployment.

The `node_modules` folder I provide is the one resulting from running `npm install --production` since I don't want the other dependencies.

But when I go to check this function in Azure Portal, I see the following error when entering the code view:

> Function (FunctionC) Error: Can't figure out which ctor to call.

The function itself looks like this in TypeScript:

```js
// Omitted imports
const functionC: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, events: CustomEvent[]): Promise<void> {
    try {
        // Extract data about Cosmos database and container
        const cosmosOutBinding = await FunctionUtil.getBindingByName(context.executionContext.functionDirectory, "documentOut")

        const cosmosConnection: CosmosDB = new CosmosDB(process.env.COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING, cosmosOutBinding.databaseName)
        const updateContext: UpdateContext = new UpdateContext(context, cosmosConnection, cosmosOutBinding.collectionName)

        await updateContext.handleEvents(events)
    } catch (error) {
        context.log.error('Failed', error)
    }
}

export default functionC
```

The `UpdateContext` is a imported class and contains the main logic of the function. I've structured it this way to have it testable.

And finally, the bindings for this function:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "some-hub",
      "connection": "EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "events"
    },
    {
      "name": "documentOut",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "dev",
      "collectionName": "asdf",
      "createIfNotExists": false,
      "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't wrap my head around what is wrong here. Any pointers in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this before with incomplete `function.json`, try adding `"createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true` to your Cosmos output binding.

Comment: @evilSnobu Thanks, but that property is not in the json schema (I think its `createIfNotExists`). I don't think that's it. I'm using cosmos as both in and out for the same collection in other functions.

Comment: I found the issue... We create our infrastructure using terraform and terraform defaults to version 1 of the function runtime. I created a new function app in the portal, and that defaults to 3. Deploying to that manually created runtime works.

Comment: You should probably still report this on https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions. Seems like a honest mistake to make and the runtime should be able to at least give you a more meaningful error back.

Comment: I will do that. It seems that this specific error message is pretty prolific and most are some version mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create our infrastructure using terraform and terraform defaults to version 1 of the function runtime. I created a new function app in the portal, and that defaults to 3. Deploying to that manually created runtime works.